# Linear fractional transformation (complex analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

Question:

1. Find a conformal map $f(z)$ which maps the disk 
   $$D=\left\{z \in\mathbb{C}\vert|z-1|<1\right\}$$
   one-to-one and onto the upper half plane.
2. Find a conformal map $f(z)$ which maps the disk 
   $$D=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}\vert|z-1|<1\right\}$$
   one-to-one and onto the set 
   $$W=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}|0<\operatorname{Arg}(z)<\pi/4\right\}.$$

For part 1, I think I can just pick three points on the circle, and three points on the real axis to map them to, preserving orientation, and then use the cross ratio formula to find the LFT. I have no idea how to proceed for part 2. What if I were to, say, compose what I obtained in part 1 with the transformation $z^\frac14$?

Comment: Both great ideas!